# CiviSMS extension

Tags: installation, civisms

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.6 on Drupal 7.43 on a CentOS 7 platform. I need to install CiviSMS with the Twilio and am running into a problem with the PHP version requirement of 5.5. CentOS natively has PHP 5.4.16. Can anyone advise on a better platform that gives me the ability to run CiviSMS?

Comment: This question is really not about Civi at all. Try a Linux forum.

Comment: Which is requiring PHP 5.5, CiviSMS or Twilio? We run CiviSMS with Twilio on PHP 5.4...

Comment: I have PHP and MySQL at the proper versions now on CentOS 7.  Working on the install of Twilio, but directions on civiCRM suggest Twilio is not an option.  I have civiCRM 4.7.9 on Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your hosting, you might be able to upgrade PHP on your CentOS server.  A quick Google search showed some options, but I can't vouch for any particular guide.

I tend to work more on the Ubuntu/Debian side of things, and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ships with PHP 5.5.9 out of the box.  (And Ubuntu 16.04 gives you the option of PHP 5.6 or PHP 7.0, which isn't yet supported by CiviCRM.)  If you aren't set in your ways, you might try switching over.

Comment: I'm investigating Ubuntu 16.04 now but less familiar with sysadmin on that platform.  So I was curious if anyone had a solid solution on CentOS or other similar platform.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think whatever PHP requirement you have is coming from CiviCRM or the Twilio extension.  CiviCRM definitely doesn't require PHP 5.5 - and the Twilio code hasn't really changed for years, so I can't imagine that requires it either.

Please post a screenshot of the screen that says you need PHP 5.5 and maybe folks can help you more.